# MySql table names and field names within quotations

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a bunch of PHP code that is auto-generated and it puts all table names and field names within quotes.  To wit:

```
INSERT INTO "t_ML_u_Visitor"("c_u_ID") VALUES ...
```

Since the code is Auto-Generated it would be much preferred if I could somehow get MySql to accept this syntax rather than subjecting the generated code to a post-process, that strips the quotes.

I have tried this:

```
$conn=$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
$R=$conn->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "SET SQL_MODE = 'ANSI'");
```

But to no avail.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal quote character is the back-quote - eg

```
create table `quoted`( `v` varchar(10) );
```

Can you change the quote character your auto-generated queries use to suit ?

EDIT:  I just tried ANSI mode, and it does what you want:

```
set @session sql_mode = ANSI;
create table "world"( "v" varchar(10));
```

The problem then becomes that double-quote can no longer be used to quote literal strings.

Comment: I don't use PHP, but I think you just run the "set session" statement separately as any other SQL statement using the $conn->query() command:  its effect will hold for the duration of your connection to the database.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL uses backticks (`) to escape.
Your query then looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `t_ML_u_Visitor` (`c_u_ID`) VALUES (...)
```

If you are using PHP and Mysqli (as I see) you can use the function real_escape_string() of mysqli like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
$query = "INSERT INTO t_ML_u_Visitor (c_u_ID) VALUES (...)";
$escaped = $conn->real_escape_string($query);
$result = $conn->query($escaped);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: No No No...  I realize that I can simply remove the quotes and fix everything.  The quotes are already there.  I would like to set the SQL_MODE to ANSI from PHP and have it work WITHOUT removing the quotes from all the auto-generated queries.

Comment: hmm.. I checked out some things and found the sourcecode of joomla using mysqli. They use simply `$conn->query("SET SQL_MODE = 'ANSI'");` as Martin said.
sry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377743/what-is-character-called/3377836#3377836 quotes quotes quotes...