# What is '`' character called?

Tags: character, ascii, special-characters, terminology, punctuation

I feel silly for asking this but it isn't like I could google this.

What is the <kbd>`</kbd> character called? In case it doesnt show up, it is the character used for inline code with markdown. Also, on most keyboards, it shares the key with <kbd>~</kbd>.

**I like all three answers so I made this a CW instead of accepting**

Comment: I think the only place I've seen this used is in SAP.

Comment: @Kirk: Also used in *nix shells to execute a command and return its output in an express. Used in PowerShell as an escape character in double quoted strings. Used in TeX as an opening quote (converted to the correct typographical glyph). SO lots of use.

Comment: Used in Python, equivalent to `repr`.

Comment: +1 for using the correct quotation marks in the question ;)

Comment: And it is used to open the console in Quake ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

All sorts of things, but in programming mostly the back-quote or backtick,

Answer (score 21):

**Grave** (pronounced Grahv, not like the synonym for tomb) or **Grave accent**.

Comment: Does that mean that the single-quote (') is really the acute accent?

Comment: No, the acute accents is ´ (used on things like the Es in résumé). Single quotes are just called single quotation marks or apostrophes depending on usage (although single quotation marks and apostrophes are technically two distinct symbols).

Comment: this page calls it backquote, interesting. You both answered my Q tho. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Comment: As Neil mentioned, it's called a back-tick or a backquote in programming contexts, but in most other contexts, it's a grave. In your example of markdown, it'd be more appropriately called a backquote/back-tick.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html), the prime nerd reference which really should be an ISO standard :-)

> *Common*: backquote; left quote; left single quote; open quote; ; grave.
>
> *Rare*: backprime; backspark; unapostrophe; birk; blugle; back tick; back glitch; push; opening single quotation mark; quasiquote.

Comment: With Unicode the opening single quote is a different character though.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Unicode table to find name of the symbol. There are utilities which let you search it, like `gucharmap`. It gives U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT for this symbol.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377743/what-is-character-called/3377755#3377755) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377743/what-is-character-called/3377751#3377751) provides a good definition.

In laymen's terms "**[no-shift-tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe)**" is also useful in PHP for keeping mySQL statements from crashing on single quotes on the table name.

```
SELECT * from `the_table_name` WHERE id=1 // best practice
```

For some reason certain PHP servers will [choke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote) on this:

```
SELECT * from 'the_table_name' WHERE id=1 // not preferred method
```

This normally works, but doesn't pass nice in strings:

```
SELECT * from "the_table_name" WHERE id=1 // how to escape this string?
```

Other than that, I don't use it much.